# starred list variable swapping in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I have a conceptual question. I have a few code snippets and their corresponding outputs

```
ls = [1,2,3,4]
a = '?'
a, *ls = *ls, a
```

`a: 1` `ls: [2, 3, 4, '?']`

```
ls = [1,2,3,4]
a = '?'
a, *ls = ls, a
```

`a: [1, 2, 3, 4]` `ls: ['?']`

```
ls = [1,2,3,4]
a = '?'
a, ls = *ls, a
```

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

The first one makes sense to me, but examples 2 and 3 leave me confused. Why are the outputs for the 2nd and 3rd example the way they are?

Comment: I don't see how you can understand the first but not the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1 assigns 5 elements (`*ls, a`). The first goes to the first variable and the rest to the starred variable (`a, *ls`).

Example 2 assigns 2 elements (`ls, a`). The first element goes to the first variable and the rest (i.e. the other element) to the starred variable (`a, *ls`).

Example 3 attempts to assign 5 elements (`*ls, a`) to exactly two variables. This would leave 3 values unassigned, so you get an error.